# Why JQuery library of append method is not working on partial AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This library is working fine in index file, but when I use it on a partial, it is not working. Here is my partial code:

```
<html ng-app="firstApp">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
          $("p").append(" <b>Appended paragraph</b>.");
        });
        $("#btn2").click(function(){
          $("ol").append("<li>Appended item</li>");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <ol>
      <li>List item 1</li>
      <li>List item 2</li>
      <li>List item 3</li>
    </ol>

    <button id="btn1">Append text</button>
    <button id="btn2">Append list item</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click','#btn1',function() {....})` -- or better yet, use [`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) to toggle it.

Comment: Should try and avoid jQuery DOM manipulation when using Angular, fyi.

Comment: Blazemonger i try it but still not working

Comment: Build a demonstration on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) -- as it is, your code is not using partials, so it's hard to diagnose the problem.

Comment: You can add code examples directly in stackoverflow now fyi

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/pZUcdWBjXkSSsviwKo5x?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var app = angular.module('firstApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.appendText = function(text) {
        angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("p")).append(text);
    };
    $scope.appendListElement = function(listElement) {
        angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("ol")).append('<li>' + listElement + '</li>');
    };
});
```

HMTL:

```
<html ng-app="firstApp">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
        <ol>
            <li>List item 1</li>
            <li>List item 2</li>
            <li>List item 3</li>
        </ol>

        <button id="btn1" ng-click="appendText('some Text')">Append text</button>
        <button id="btn2" ng-click="appendListElement('some element')">Append list item</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/CbudpwhIngYHkMxoqiC2?p=preview